# Handle Scenarios when exposing route as a restlet service

Tags: apache-camel, restlet

I have used rest servlet binding to expose route as a service.

I have used `employeeClientBean` as a POJO , wrapping the actual call to employee REST service within it, basically doing the role of a service client.

So, based on the method name passed, I call the respective method in employee REST service, through the `employeeClientBean`.

I want to know how how I can handle the scenarios as added in commments in the block of code.

I am just new to Camel, but felt POJO binding is better as it does not couple us to camel specific APIs like exchange and processor or even use
any specific components.

But, I am not sure how I can handle the above scenarios and return appropriate JSON responses to the user of the route service.

Can someone help me on this.

```
   public void configure() throws Exception {
       restConfiguration().component("servlet").bindingMode(RestBindingMode.json)
        .dataFormatProperty("prettyPrint", "true")
        .contextPath("camelroute/rest").port(8080);
            rest("/employee").description("Employee Rest Service")
                    .consumes("application/json").produces("application/json")

        .get("/{id}").description("Find employee by id").outType(Employee.class)
            .to("bean:employeeClientBean?   method=getEmployeeDetails(${header.id})")


            //How to handle and return response to the user of the route service for the following scenarios for get/{id}"

                //1.Passed id is not a valid one as per the system

                //2.Failure to return details due to some issues



        .post().description("Create a new Employee ").type(Employee.class)
            .to("bean:employeeClientBean?method=createEmployee");


            //How to handle and return correct response to the user of the route service for the following scenarios "

                //1. Employee being created already exists in the system

                //2. Some of the fields of employee passed are as not as per constraints on them 

                //3. Failure to create a employee due to some issues in server side (For Eg, DB Failure)
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I fear you are putting Camel to bad use - as per the Apache [documentation](https://camel.apache.org/rest-dsl.html) the REST module is supporting Consumer implementations, e.g. reading from a REST-endpoint, but **NOT** writing back to a caller.

For your use case you might want to switch framework. Syntactically, [Ratpack](http://ratpack.io/manual/current/quick-start.html) goes in that direction.